# InDesign: Is there a way to make tables with multiple headers?

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, tables

I'm currently working on a page featuring multiple cities and addresses, that I've set up as a table inside an indesign document. Here's my desired outcome:
[image: Table with multiple cities spanning over columns of text]

While I could make it work by just making different cell styles and applying them each time a new city header is required, some cities end up spanning multiple text columns, and with new addresses being added or removed every month, I wished to make something that would automatically span the headers as necessity requires.

I don't seem to find a way to make a single table with multiple headers alternating between normal body cell types. Alternatively, is there a way to make multiple tables fit inside a text box and ajust positioning as the tables grow bigger/smaller?

Comment: Can’t you just convert the rows you want to header rows? That should work, as far as I can tell…

Comment: Indesign is not allowing me to convert "middle" rows to anything but footers, it only allows me to create new headers right underneath the first one

Comment: You can set the *cell or row style* to match. You don't actually designate them as defined "header rows". Similar to how you'd merely assign paragraph styles to headers within text blocks.

Comment: You don't need tables for that type of listing. @Wolff is correct in his answer below good old formatted paragraphs will be easier to control here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is actually quite advanced. You want to be able to manually define headers in a table, but if a non-header ends up in the top of a column, you want InDesign to automatically insert a duplicate of the last header. Am I right?

As far as I know, there isn't a built-in function to help you with this. This isn't how table headers work. They are always in the beginning of a column, frame or page. To automate this, you would have to write a script.

I'll show you how I would do it. I wouldn't use tables for something like this, but style it all only using *Paragraph Styles*. So much easier to edit, so perhaps adding the repeated headers manually won't be too much work.

All you really need is two *Paragraph Styles* (one for the city name and one for the  contact info) and an *Object Style* for the icons/portraits (or whatever those black squares are).

[image]

**Icon Object Style**: Has *Text Wrap* on the right side. Perhaps it has its *Size* defined by the styling and additional styling.

**City Paragraph Style**: Aligned to center. The background color comes from a *Paragraph Rule*. Has *Keep Options > Keep with Next* set to *1 lines* to make sure it doesn't end up in the bottom of a column.

**Info Paragraph Style**: Has an icon pasted in as an *Anchored Object* in the beginning of each paragraph. Has *Drop Caps* set to *2 lines* and *1 character* to make the icon span over two lines. Has *Keep Options > Keep Lines Together > All Lines in Paragraph* enabled to make sure the address and telephone number always stick together.

With this set up, I would simply style all the text and then go through each column and add the previous city name when needed.

[image]

Next time, if there are many edits, I would perhaps delete the extra city names, make the edits and add the extra city names again. A bit cumbersome perhaps, but that really depends on how many pages of this you have.